# How do I delete one row for two duplicate entries in a postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

The two rows have all same columns except a timestamp column - created_at

I just want to retain one of these rows - doesn't matter which.

This is how I am able to select one of each of these duplicate rows that I can delete on the basis of the created_at column which has the lesser value.

```
 select e.id, e.user_id, e.r_needed, e.match, e.status, e.stage, e.created_at 
    from employee e, employee e2 where e.id=e2.id and e.user_id=e2.user_id and 
     e.status = 12 and e2.status=12 and e.stage=false and e2.stage=false and 
     e.match=true and e2.match=true and e.user_id=12 and e.r_needed=true and e2.r_needed=true
     and e.created_at<e2.created_at and DATE(e.created_at)='2015-10-08';
```

However, cannot figure how I can delete this row such that both of the duplicates do not get deleted and only the ones that are selected above do?

Basically, I want to delete all rows that match the columns in my select query above and the row which has the lesser value for created_at.

My table has no primary key or unique key.

Comment: Use row number with an appropriate partition and then delete where the row number is 1 only.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: better use **row_number > 1** instead :)

Comment: Can you please give me example how I can use that in my query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Correlated Subquery instead of a join:

```
select * from employee e
where exists
 ( select * from employee e2 
   where e.id=e2.id and e.user_id=e2.user_id 
     and e.status = 12 and e2.status=12 and e.stage=false 
     and e2.stage=false and e.match=true and e2.match=true 
     and e.user_id=12 and e.r_needed=true and e2.r_needed=true
     and e.created_at<e2.created_at 
     and DATE(e.created_at)='2015-10-08'
 );
```

If this returns the duplicate rows correctly you can switch to `delete` instead of `select *`.